# Couchbase CBQ Silent Fail

Tags: couchbase

I'm trying to query a secure bucket via couchbase CBQon windows.

I've got couchbase/bin in my PATH and from the command line I am able to run this:

```
cbq -engine=http://localhost:8091 -c=hug_contenthub:password
```

seems to connect OK:

```
Connected to : http://localhost:8091/. Type Ctrl-D or \QUIT to exit.
Path to history file for the shell : C:\Users\kevin\.cbq_history
cbq>_
```

From here on I can't do anything except quit.  I tried several commands:

```
cbq> select 1=1
   > SELECT DISTINCT type FROM `beer-sample`
   > create primary index on `beer-sample`
```

They are all ignored.  No feedback at all.  The only thing that changes is cqb> becomes "....>" the cqb bit is stripped off.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm relatively new to [Couchbase Server](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/introduction/intro.html), and I'm used to the old MS SQL ways, and so I think I had a similar problem.

My solution: I added a 'semicolon' at the end of each query.

I also tend to prefer to use the new [Query Workbench tool](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.5/tools/query-workbench.html) instead of [cbq](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/tools/cbq-shell.html#topic_bzd_zwr_w5) when I'm just writing and tweaking N1QL queries. (But maybe that's just me).

Comment: Yes, the lack of a semicolon is exactly the problem. The ">" means that cbq is expecting you to continue the query, since it allows multi-line queries. It only processes the query once you enter ';' and hit return.

Comment: Don't feel bad, I'm hardly a schoolboy and I made the same mistake :)